# Paypal logo in Prestashop checkout

Tags: prestashop, graphical-logo

Good evening,

I use PayPal module on my website developped with Prestashop 1.5.5
I would like to modify the logo which appears at the end of the checkout process because it's too large for my theme.
So I removed the file FR_bnr_horizontal_solution_PP_327wx80h.gif in the folder module/paypal/img/logos/ and replaced it with a new image with the same name.

Moreover, nothing change, the previous logo was always active and the correspondaing file FR_bnr_horizontal_solution_PP_327wx80h.gif was re-created in the folder.

What should I do to resolve this issue ? Which file must I modified ?

Thanks in advance.

Samuel

Answer (score 0):

Through browsers developers extension, check which is the image your template is using.

Then change it in `modules/paypal/img/logos`.

In my case it was the file `PT_vertical_solution_PPeCheck.gif`, where PT is the code language.